# Component not rendering in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

## Imported component to my app.js file but it is not rendering?

I built a topbar-component in another file but not able to render the topbar-component in my app.js file.

#### APP.js >

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import topbarComponent from "./topbar";

function App() {
  return (

    <div className="App">
      {topbarComponent}
      <div className="VideoGrid">
      </div>
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

#### Topbar.js>

```js
import React from "react"
const topbarComponent = () => {
  return (
    <header className="top_bar">
      <span><sapn>Video</sapn>Share</span>
      <nav>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}

export default topbarComponent
```

Comment: Write it as `<TopBarComponent />`. And the Component name should start with Uppercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React component names should start with an uppercase letter. your topbarComponent should then become TopbarComponent.

**Topbar.js**

```js
import React from "react"
const TopbarComponent = () => {
  return (
    <header className="top_bar">
      <span><sapn>Video</sapn>Share</span>
      <nav>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}

export default TopbarComponent
```

Rendering a component is similar to returning html tags, where the angle brackets are used to do so. instead of {topbarComponent}, this would become

**App.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import TopbarComponent from "./topbar";

function App() {
  return (

    <div className="App">
      <TopbarComponent />
      <div className="VideoGrid">
      </div>
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

curly braces, which you have used, are used when wanting to return a value of a variable within the jsx (react elements)

Comment: please write a small description in order to better help the user understand :)